# Not able to increment a counter variable inside my viewmodel

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

I have an application where i'm binding my viewmodel to the main activity lifecycle and i do increment a counter based on which lifecyle has been called , but i'm not able to increment the counters variable , any reason why , Thank yo

- This is my viewmodel class

```
 class CounterViewModel : ViewModel(), DefaultLifecycleObserver {


    private var onCreateCounter = 0
    private var onStartCounter = 0
    private var onResumeCounter = 0


    // This class defines the ViewModel which keeps track of the number of times onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() have been called.
    companion object {
        private const val TAG = "CounterViewModel"
    }

    // TODO :
    // Create variables to keep a track of the number of times onCreate(), onStart() and onResume() have been called.
    // To keep track of each count, define two variables as specified below.
    // Define a private variable of type MutableLiveData that can only be modified within the ViewModel class.
    // Define an internal/public variable of type LiveData that can be accessed externally by the UI/fragment but cannot be modified.
    // Use a backing property to specify the getter function for the internal/public variable
    // Refer to the link below for a more detailed explanation/example
    // https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-viewmodel#4

    private val _onStartMutableLiveData  : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(onStartCounter)
    val onStartLiveData : LiveData<Int> get() = _onStartMutableLiveData

    private val _onCreateMutableLiveData  : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(onCreateCounter)
    val onCreateLiveData : LiveData<Int> get() = _onCreateMutableLiveData

    private val _onResumeMutableLiveData  : MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData(onResumeCounter)
    val onResumeLiveData : LiveData<Int> get() = _onResumeMutableLiveData


    val onCreateProperty : LiveData<Int>
     get()  {
         return onCreateLiveData
     }

    val onStartProperty : LiveData<Int>
        get()  {
            return onStartLiveData
        }

    val onResumeProperty : LiveData<Int>
        get()  {
            return onResumeLiveData
        }


    internal fun bindToActivityLifecycle(mainActivity: MainActivity) {
        // TODO :
        // Add the current instance of CounterViewModel as a LifeCycleObserver to the MainActivity
        // Use the addObserver function
        mainActivity.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }


    override fun onResume(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onResume(owner)
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        Log.i(TAG,"Entered onResume")
        onResumeCounter++
        _onResumeMutableLiveData.value = onResumeCounter
    }

    override fun onCreate(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onCreate(owner)
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        Log.i(TAG,"Entered onCreate")
        onCreateCounter++
        _onCreateMutableLiveData.value = onCreateCounter

    }


    override fun onStart(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
        super.onStart(owner)
        // Update the appropriate count variable
        Log.i(TAG,"Entered onStart")
        onStartCounter++
        _onStartMutableLiveData.value = onStartCounter

    }

}
```

** Fragment Code

```
 class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    /** Binding to XML layout */
    private lateinit var binding: FirstFragmentBinding
    // Create a variable of type CounterViewModel to keep track of counts
    private lateinit var viewModel: CounterViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        // Use the provided binding object to inflate the layout.
        binding = FirstFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        // Update ActionBar label to distinguish which Fragment is displayed
        (requireActivity() as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = this.javaClass.simpleName

        // Set onClickListener to navigate to the second fragmant from the first
        binding.fab.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().navigate(FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment())
        }
        // Return the root view.
        return binding.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        // TODO:
        // Initialize CounterViewModel instance
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this)[CounterViewModel::class.java]
        // TODO:
        // Use binding to display initial counts
        binding.onCreate.text = "onCreate Called : ${viewModel.onCreateLiveData.value}"
        binding.onStart.text = "onStart Called : ${viewModel.onStartLiveData.value}"
        binding.onResume.text = "onResume Called : ${viewModel.onResumeLiveData.value}"
        // The function below updates the counts over time
        beginObservingCounter()
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    private fun beginObservingCounter() {

        // TODO:
        // Register observers for each of the count variables
        // In the body of the observe function, update the text to be displayed by using the binding
        viewModel.onStartLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ counter ->
            binding.onStart.text = "onStart Called Again $counter"
        }

        viewModel.onCreateLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ counter ->
            binding.onCreate.text = "onCreate Called Again $counter"
        }

        viewModel.onResumeLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){ counter ->
            binding.onResume.text = "onResume Called Again $counter"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that the DefaultLifecycleObserver methods are in fact getting called either via breakpoints or checking your logs? if they are not, have you verified that you are in fact attaching the viewModel as an observer to the appropriate lifecycle?

Also, I'd recommend not using the viewModel as a lifecycleObserver and instead calling the appropriate viewModel functions from the lifecycle functions directly.

Comment: Yes the log messages are showing when i launch the app , also when i rotate the screen they are called again , basically the only thing is that counters are not incrementing at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that an *init block* gets called when you rotate - which init block? Rotating the screen should give you the same `ViewModel` instance with all its state intact, that's the point of them. Maybe you're initialising them the wrong way, maybe creating another copy and observing `LiveData` from *that* instead of the instance that's actually watching your lifecycle and incrementing?

For what it's worth, your code works fine for me in an `Activity` like this:

```
val counterViewModel: CounterViewModel by viewModels()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    counterViewModel.bindToActivityLifecycle(this)
    // onResumeProperty works too since it's the same thing!
    counterViewModel.onResumeLiveData.observe(this) { count ->
        Toast.makeText(this, "Resumes: $count", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

I get a Toast every time `onResume` happens - well technically it happens more often since it observes the old data first when rotating, then gets the new value when you hit `onResume` again, but it does work! So I'd make sure you're handling the right instances

Comment: Can you please print the counter and tell me if it gets increments everytime the screen is rotated , cause lifecycle functions are triggered and the live data observer is working as well , but the counter is not incrementing , can you please check if it does increment for you  , Thank you

Comment: @Taki well I mean it must be incrementing because you're calling `++` on the counter variable, right? That's `counter = counter + 1`, so the value of `counter` must be increasing for the number to keep going up. And that's the value that's being set on the `LiveData` each time, which is what my `Toast` is displaying. Have you tried debugging your app? Stick a breakpoint in one of those lifecycle functions where you increment the counter, and you can see the value of everything when it pauses

Comment: The whole point is about the counter itself which is not incrementing even though it has ++ and posting the value through mutablelivedata , everything works fine but the counter , when i observe the counter ,it is always the same value , never increments , that's why i asked you if you can tell me if it is incrementing for you , if yes then i got something wrong with my code

Comment: @Taki yeah like I said your code works fine for me, hooked up to my Activity with the code I posted. The `count` observer param increases as I rotate and navigate away from the app, and since that value is being calculated from the `counter` variable each time (whatever it was before + 1) then it's being incremented fine. You're not reading the current value in the `LiveData` and incrementing that or anything, you're reading the counter value. Try what I posted and see if it works for you - it should! Then see what you're doing differently. If you post your `MainActivity` code that might help

Comment: Thank you , i'm actually observing the values inside a fragment , i will update the code with fragment code , if you want to take a look , thank you

Comment: @Taki where are you calling `bindToActivityLifecycle`? In your Activity? That `ViewModel` you're grabbing there is specific to your `FirstFragment` class: `ViewModelProvider(this)[CounterViewModel::class.java]` - if you're calling the same code in `MainActivity` (so `this` is a `MainActivity` instead) then you'll get a different `CounterViewModel` instance, with its own counter variables and `LiveData` objects. If you're doing that, you need to pass your *Activity* to `viewModelProvider()` in the `Fragment`, so you get the same one the Activity is using - it's how you share a VM between frags

Comment: If you wanted to do that the Kotlin way like in my code, you'd do `val viewModel: CounterViewModel by activityViewModels()` - it basically grabs the parent Activity's copy of that VM, which is the same thing just written a bit more nicely! `by viewModels()` grabs *that class's own copy*, which is why I used it in the Activity - and sometimes a `Fragment` will have its own personal VMs that aren't for sharing, so you'd use it there too. But in your case, you need to share it (if your Activity *is* binding itself)

Comment: You were totally right , so basically i had to pass requireactivity inside the viewmodelprovider() and it works , thank you mate , appreciate your time and help

Comment: No worries! Glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out that while the definition of `operator fun inc()` is used for `++`, they do not do the same thing, `0.inc()` is valid, whereas `0++` is not. Turns out that all `inc` does is return the value plus 1 (see the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int/inc.html)) and `++` calls `inc` but then also sets the new value. So, you can either change out for using `++` or do `onStartCounter = onStartCounter.inc()`

Comment: I did actually try ++ as well and it did not work , it only increases the counter from 0 to 1  , then it stops incrementing ... weird , i got confused

Comment: Well, that seems odd, because AFAIK `++` should always be incrementing, but maybe there is somehow a bug with those values being via a delegate instead of straight vars (which not sure why you need them to be Delegates.notNull if you initialize them in the init block anyway, you may as well initialize them directly), but in theory, it shouldn't matter if they are delegates or not. If it for some reason does, then it could be a Kotlin bug.

Comment: So far what i noticed is that init block was called everytime i rotate the screen for example , it resets the values to 0 , that's what i discovered now , i beleive everytime the viewmodel is called it will reset the values , anyway to prevent that , Thank you , i updated the code if you want to take a look ,